# Angularjs - directive to present html and ng markup stored in $scope/model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My scenario is that I need to present HTML content coming from a database. The HTML content contains expressions and ng specific attributes/elements. I've been directed into the realms of directives - but I am uncertain on how to achieve this - since I am not able to access the $scope where I am able to return the template field:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);


    app.directive('dataPresenter', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: 'true',
            template: ???How_To_Access $scope.data or the value of ng-model???
        };
    });


    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.field = true;
          $scope.data = "<b ng-if='field'>{{1+1}}</b>"                
     });


...
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <data-presenter ng-model="data"></data-presenter>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to create an isolate scope, then you can add a `scope` parameter to your directive definition.  The scope parameter lets you define how data should be passed to your directive.

The angularjs docs include an example: [http://plnkr.co/edit/ngdoc:example-example85@snapshot?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/ngdoc%3aexample-example85@snapshot?p=preview)

Comment: but then how can I assign that to the template field?

Comment: The fields all end up as properties on $scope.  You can use `$scope.whatever` in your controller or `{{whatever}}` in your template.  To render html I think you will need special treatment from the $sce service, but I'm not sure about that - if you can manage to avoid storing html in your database, I'd investigate that~